# Django подставить имя пользователя в форму автоматически

Tags: django

Доброго времени суток!

Есть в Django 2 таблицы, связанные между собой. А именно стандартная таблица User и созданная Links с полем user которое является ForeignKey.

```
forms.py

class AddLink(forms.ModelForm):
    full_link = forms.CharField(required=True)
    short_link = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Links
        fields = ['full_link', 'short_link']



model.py

class Links(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
        full_link = models.CharField('Полные ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)
        short_link = models.CharField('Короткие ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Ccылка'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Ссылки'
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.full_link
```

Есть форма добавления информации в таблицу Links, в котором должно быть 2 поля: full_link и short_link. Соответственно чтобы добавить запись в таблицу Links пользователь вводит в форме 2 значения, но при этом чтобы запись в таблицу была добавлена надо также указать последнюю обязательную графу в виде пользователя, который эту запись добавляет. Как его можно подставить в поле не спрашивая об этом пользователя и по умолчанию подставить текущего авторизованного пользователя?

```
views.py

def link(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    addUserLink = AddLink(request.POST)
    if addUserLink.is_valid():
        addUserLink.user = request.user
        addUserLink.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Ссылка добавлена')
else:
    addUserLink = AddLink()
    
        return render(request, 'users/links.html', {'userLinks': userLinks, 'title':'Пользовательские ссылки', 'addUserLink': addUserLink})
```

Исправил views.py, провел миграции. В вопросе обновил код. Все равно выдает ошибку NOT NULL constraint failed: users_links.user_id при попытке сохранить форму. Я так понимаю надо еще как то определить поле user в форме? Его следует записать как CharField?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте поле `user` необязательным:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Не забудьте выполнить миграции.

Далее, во `views` подставьте авторизированнного пользователя:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    addUserLink = AddLink(request.POST)
    if addUserLink.is_valid():
        addUserLink.user = request.user
        addUserLink.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Ссылка добавлена')
```

Comment: Надо ли в форме объявлять поле user при этом? Я отредактировал вопрос, подставил ваш код. Ошибку, которую выдает Django так же написал выше

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать так:

```
models.py

class Links(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    full_link = models.CharField('Полные ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)
    short_link = models.CharField('Короткие ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ccылка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ссылки'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_link

views.py

def link(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        addUserLink = AddLink(request.POST)
        print(addUserLink)
        if addUserLink.is_valid():
            instance = addUserLink.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Ссылка добавлена')
    else:
        addUserLink = AddLink()

forms.py

class AddLink(forms.ModelForm):
    full_link = forms.CharField(required=True)
    short_link = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Links
        fields = ['full_link', 'short_link', 'author']
```

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно поле в форму добавлять, если создать объект в место сохранения формы (username + данные полученные из формы).

Например:

```
if form.is_valid():
    username = request.user
    first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
    last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    address = form.cleaned_data['address']
    postal_code = form.cleaned_data['postal_code']
    city = form.cleaned_data['city']
        
    Model_name.objects.create(username=username,
                              first_name=first_name,
                              last_name=last_name,
                              email=email,
                              address=address,
                              postal_code=postal_code,
                              city=city)
```