# Как сохранять данные в модели дополнительно к полученным из ModelForm

Tags: python, django

Мне необходимо сохранить в БД экземпляр модели на основе POST-данных формы, но с условием, что `author` я беру не из формы (и даже поле такое в форму не вывожу), а из `request.user`.

В документации (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) предлагается решение:

```
form = PartialAuthorForm(request.POST)
author = form.save(commit=False)
author.title = 'Mr'
author.save()
```

Как воспроизвести пример в консоли понятно, но где именно в моем приложении я должен реализовать такую логику? И как передать в форму request.user?

Вот основные файлы приложения:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    event_describe = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Marker)

class Marker(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**form.py**

```
class CreatePostForm(ModelForm):

    tags_field=CharField(max_length=70)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('event_describe', 'event_location')
```

**views.py**

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    form_class = CreatePostForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['author'] = self.request.user
        return context
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Вы прекрасно оформили вопрос, но на SO используется модель, когда один вопрос содержит одну конкретную проблему и если у вас возникает ряд вопросов, то для каждого создается отдельный. Мое вам предложение разбить вопрос на два. Хотя на первый ответ - очевидно в функции расположенной во `views.py`, request.user не передается в форму, а есть сущность авторизированного пользователя в данный момент на странице

Comment: Да, действительно, это мой первый опыт. @Dmitry, можете уточнить работу какой именно функции в PostCreateView я должен переопределить в этом случае?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Django подставить имя пользователя в форму автоматически](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166779/django-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

В функции вьюхи прописать что-то вида

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form=FormClass(request.POST)
        obj=App(**form.cleaned_data)
        obj.author='new author'
        obj.save()
```

В функции вида создаём новый объект модели с данными из пост метода, затем изменяем нужную характеристику и сохраняем, не забывая про валидацию

Comment: Получается, что я должен запретить CreatePostForm вызывать метод save(), который отвечает за сохранение текущего экземпляра модели в БД, и делать это на стороне PostCreateView?
Кукую именно функцию вьюхи я должен переопределить, чтобы следовать новому алгоритму создания объекта модели?

Comment: функцию которая принимает пост данные, то есть та на которую идёт отправка формы

Comment: создает и принимает данные от формы PostCreateView:


`urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
]`


А куда дальше "копать"?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже разобрался

Нужно переопределить у PostCreateView метод form_valid(), который вызывает (в случае, если данные из формы успешно провалидированы) form.save() для сохранения экземпляра модели.

Здесь можно изменить стандартную логику работы вьюхи. В моем случае вот так работает:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, firstly save with commit=False argument the associated model."""
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        # возвращаем form_valid предка
        return super().form_valid(form)
        # или формируем response самостоятельно
        #return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Странно, что в официальной документации не пишут про это...